# cannot connect to SQL with managment studio

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sql-server, azure-vm-role

I created a virtual machine with SQL in Azure. but I can't connect with management studio (SSMS) from out of my VM

[image]

any idea?

Comment: Have you opened port 1433 in both the VM and Azure firewall?

Answer (score 1):

There is no trusted CA certificate in the root store of the VM . 
Either you get a certificate and install that and have

> Encrypt= true

in the connection string or  you have to set

> TrustServerCertificate=True

in the connection string or in the connection properties of the login pop up screen in SQL server management studio.